# Trying to create a Random Matrix for Grasshopper, but NO result

Tags: python, grasshopper, rhino3d

I´ve just using Python for creating a Random Matrix, but no results.Width and Height are defined in outside in Grasshopper. Any suggestions?

```py
#imports

import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import math 
import random as rnd

#for accesing GH classes - JUST IN CASE

import clr
clr.AddReference("Grasshopper") 
from Grasshopper.Kernel.Data import *
from Grasshopper import DataTree

#create a Matrix

def initMatrix(rndSeed):
    global A0
    global B0
    
    tempVals=[]
    rnd.seed(rndSeed)
    for i in range (height):
        thisA = []  # empty list
        thisB = []  # empty list
        for j in range (width):
            thisA.append(rnd.random()*12+ rnd.random()*2)
            thisB.append(rnd.random()*12+ rnd.random()*2)
        tempVals.append(thisA)
        
#       A0.append(thisA)
#       B0.append(thisB)

    return tempVals


# Call the initMatrix function

    a=initMatrix(0.1)
```

[image]

"RESOLUTION" bar will give visible results in the lower yellow panel connected to "A".

Comment: `are defined in outside in Grasshopper` what does it mean

Comment: the first "in" is a typo. The bar marked in purple (RESOLUTION) allows me to define the weight and height values. The results are visible in the window that says "null".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have invalid indentations in your script. The comments above the `return tempVals` will cause it to be interpreted outside your function. The indentation of `a=initMatrix(0.1)` also looks incorrect and should not be indented. Additionally, if you are creating a multi-dimensional array, your output will not be interpretable by Grasshopper, it will read as `IronPython.Runtime.List`. I suggest formatting your matrix as a native grasshopper tree like the example below.

```py
#imports
import random as rnd
from Grasshopper.Kernel.Data import GH_Path
from Grasshopper import DataTree

# Create a Matrix
def initMatrix(rndSeed, width, height):
    rnd.seed(rndSeed)
    tree = DataTree[object]()  # Create a DataTree object

    for i in range(height):
        path = GH_Path(i)  # Create a new path for each row
        for j in range(width):
            a_value = rnd.random()*12 + rnd.random()*2
            b_value = rnd.random()*12 + rnd.random()*2
            # Add values to the tree at the specified path
            tree.Add(a_value, path)
            tree.Add(b_value, path)
    
    return tree

# Call the initMatrix function
a = initMatrix(0.1, 10, 10)  # Example with width = 10, height = 10**strong text**
```